# What is the purpose or relationship of NumberOfWorkers and MaxParallelism options?

Tags: rebus

I hit an issue the other day where I scaled the workers `SetNumberOfWorkers` to a ridicules number expecting to see a equal jump in throughput. I could only see 5 workers doing any work at a time. Figured out the magic cap was Max Parallelism options default value is 5.

My assumption was that 1 worker equals 1 thread.

What is the purpose or relationship of `NumberOfWorkers` and `MaxParallelism` options?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I realize that it might not be obviously clear, it's actually pretty simple.

You are absolutely right that "number of workers" is the number of worker threads in this particular bus instance.

But since everything in Rebus is `async` now, one single worker can perform a ridiculous amount of work in parallel if that work can be `await`ed.

Therefore - to avoid doing too much work - the "max parallelism" concept was introduced, which puts a global max cap on how many messages to process in parallel.

Which values to use depends on the type of work you want to perform. The following are some reasonable settings:

- Work is predominantly asynchronous - you can use a few worker threads and fairly high parallelism, e.g. `.SetNumberOfWorkers(2).SetMaxParallelism(20)`
- Work is **fast** and synchronous - you can use a few worker threads and a matching parallelism, e.g. `.SetNumberOfWorkers(5).SetMaxParallelism(5)` (although setting the parallelism higher will not affect anything in this case)
- Work is **slow** and synchronous - you can use more worker threads and a matching parallelism, e.g. `.SetNumberOfWorkers(15).SetMaxParallelism(15)` (again: setting the parallelism higher will not affect anything in this case)

As you have correctly observed, since the parallelism setting puts an absolute upper cap on how many messages can be handled in parallel, it does not make sense to set the parallelism lower than the number of threads.

EDIT: I've added [this page](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/wiki/Workers-and-parallelism) to the wiki - thanks for making me realize that this concept was not explained anywhere :)

Answer (score 1):

I looked inside the Rebus code and it seems there's a mixture of plain threads and threadpool threads - the worker by itself is a plain thread, but it spawns multiple TPL Tasks and does not wait until that Task is completed and immediately tries to spawn another one (*it can do it if the receive of the message and its processing is really asynchronous*). What prevents it to spawn unlimited number of the Tasks is:

```
var parallelOperation = _parallelOperationsManager.TryBegin();

        if (!parallelOperation.CanContinue())
        {
            _backoffStrategy.Wait();
            return;
        }
```

The parallelOperationsManager prevents it to spawn more than MaxParallelism of async tasks. It uses Semaphore counter, before trying to spawn a new  Task. If the counter reaches the number of MaxParalleism, then the thread is blocked with Thread.Sleep for a short period to give time for the running tasks to complete, to decrement the semaphore counter, and allow to spawn a new Task (*which reads the backend queue and processes the message*).

So in essence - number of workers - is the number of plain NET Framework Threads, and MaxParallelism is the maximum number of the Tasks (*not really the number of threadpool threads, but they can use threadpool for async execution*) 
Without  MaxParallelism constraints a single Worker (plain thread) could spawn millions of IO bound async Tasks, but anyway can only process a single synchronous task.

If the job is totally synchronous then it will be processed on the plain Thread, and if the job contains an await for async operation, then the job up to that point of the async code will be done on a plain Thread and after the await on a threadpool thread.